# GAE not initialized JAVA

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am trying to work with Google App Engine.

I have Eclipse on my PC

and I have upgraded my Java to 1.7.0_45

Like this picture : http://ppt.cc/U9Wv

but I can't  initialized

how can I resolve it ?

thanks

Comment: This links to some sort of paste site that's half advertising, with no detail about the problem that I can see. Seriously?

Comment: I can't run GAE project

Comment: no error message on eclipse

Comment: only have Red cross on my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the following:

- In Eclipse, go to `Window -> Show View`. Select `Problems`. This should show a list of issues currently in your Project that is resulting in the Error.